How to send a value from a css checkbox submission?
The below is related to the following link: After selecting check box Instead of Tick symbol need X in html


input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox+label.css-label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked+label.css-label {
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.css-label {
  background-image: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/lite-x-red.png);
}
<form>
  <input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="demo_box_2" name="demo_lbl_2" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
  <input id="demo_box_3" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="demo_box_3" name="demo_lbl_3" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
</form>



I tried to submit the following css checkbox
<input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked/>
<label for="demo_box_2" value="true" name="demo_lbl_2" value="true" class="css-label">
  Selected Option
</label>

From the above it should have given me demo_lbl_2 = true
What am I missing?

Thank you very much. I have added the name and value to the input and it worked ;-)   
Selected Option

In a HTML form, the name and value attributes need to be on the relevant input element, not on a label. Otherwise the field and its value will not be sent to the server when the form is submitted.
<input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="demo_lbl_2" value="true" checked/>
<label for="demo_box_2" class="css-label">
  Selected Option
</label>

Reference: Your first form (from MDN)
